# Integration Problem: $ \int \sqrt{2^2 - x^2} $

Tags: calculus

> I need help finding $$ \int \sqrt{2^2 - x^2}dx $$

I have tried several approaches and I'm now lost.

Comment: Let $x=2\sin\theta$

Comment: or, what is that a graph of?

Comment: Expanding on EHE's comment, it is not a good idea to re-invent the wheel.  My Calculus textbook ("Calculus" 2nd Ed. 1966 - Apostol) simply **handed out** formulas, one of which was attack $\int R\left(x, \sqrt{a^2 - (cx + d)^2}\right)dx$ via $cx + d = a\sin t.$  Apostol (presumably) would **never** ask the student to derive such an attack.  I concur with Apostol's attitude.  If your teacher/book has put you in this position, you have a serious complaint coming.

Comment: @user2661923:  My criticism aligns with yours, but is far more pointed.  See this:  https://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Actually, I've gotten into trouble on mathSE taking this position in an *answer*, so I confine this type of remark to comments.  Also, I only watched the first 5 minutes of the youtube video that you linked to.  One possible flaw, at the undergrad level, math isn't that much harder than computer programming.  **Worse**, it is **much easier** to *butcher* teaching computer programming than it is to *butcher* teaching math.  In short, at the undergrad level, I don't see learning pc pgm'g as an alternative to learning math.  And using the computer *semi-blindly* is a little *iffy.*

Comment: @user2661923:  Don't make such comments until you see those points addressed *explicitly* (and extremely well) in that video.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm a retired professional programmer.  95% of the programmers that I worked with butchered their work to the point that the employer lost money because the code was unmaintainable.  In my experience, it is virtually impossible to prevent programmers from writing bad code, because there is no quality control on the code.  I had the same experience being taught programming: no quality control standards **enforced.**  Would you really expect a computer programming professor to downgrade code that works but is poorly written? ...see next comment

Comment: With math, the situation seems to be the exact opposite.  Although someone may present a proof in a somewhat disorganized manner, with (perhaps) unclear terminology, either the proof is valid or it isn't.  Further, math professors are going to criticize work that is poorly organized or unclear.

Comment: Use trig substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Using hint of @E.H.E, we can see that let $x=2\sin(\theta)$, so \begin{eqnarray}
\int \sqrt{4-x^{2}}dx&=&4\int \cos^{2}(\theta)d\theta\\
&=&2\theta+2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+C, \quad \theta=\arcsin(x/2) \\
&=&\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4-x^{2}}+2\arcsin\left( \frac{x}{2}\right)+C.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Remember that the integral is equivalent to the signed area under a curve in the two-dimensional case. Also remember that $x^2+y^2=r^2$ is the formula for a circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{2^2 - x^2}=2\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{2})^2}=2\sqrt{1-sin^2t}=2cost$ and say $x=2sint, t=arcsin\frac{x}{2}, \implies dx=2costdt$

Comment: What happened to $dx$?

Comment: I did not write the all integration solution. I put a hint.